# Can I claim my bags at DEL on a HEL-DEL-BOM flight?

Tags: transit, luggage, del

I am Indian citizen and travelling from Helsinki to Mumbai. My travel details are

- Helsinki to Delhi
- 3 hours layover
- Delhi to mumbai.

I want to know if it is possible to get my luggage in Delhi itself. Then I would check it in again before taking the next flight.

Comment: I don't know about India so I'll not post this as an answer, but if it's like in many other countries then you would be **required** to collect your luggage in Delhi in order to clear customs because the previous flight is international and the following flight is inside the country.

Comment: Have you tried just asking the airline?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you will collect your luggage, and submit it to a customs examination when you first arrive in India, at Delhi airport. You have to collect your luggage as an international arrival, it is not avoidable.

This is how international-to-domestic transfers usually work (except inside Europe).

After customs, there is a desk on the left, near the lifts that take you to terminal 3 domestic departures. That desk will accept your luggage for the domestic flight. Alternatively you may take it to the domestic counter yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response,But problem is i have both booking in same ticket.

Comment: @NaveenTripathi The answer says that you will have to collect your luggage, whether the two flights are on the same ticket or not.

Comment: @Naveen Whether it is one ticket or two is irrelevant. You need to collect your bag and present it for a customs inspection at Delhi.